# how to write eqn of line in complex form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Write the given equation of a straight line in complex notation:

Straight line through 1 and (-1 - i)

Attempt:

So i treated this initially just like a set of coordinates in the set of R thus (1,0)  and (-1,-1) and solved for an equation of the line:

Y = x/2 - 1/2

Now keeping in mind that i know to express a line in complex form it is going to have to look like some form of Re(az+b) = 0, where a,b are complex values

I manipulated it to:  x - 2y - 1 = 0

Now here is where i am stuck. I know x-2y is the real part of some complex number, but i can't figure out what or how to obtain it. All i know is that the product of the complex numbers a and z has to equal x-2y in the real portion of it at least.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

In the equation $x-2y-1=0$ replace $x,y$ by their expressions $x=\frac {z+\bar z}{2}, y=\frac {z-\bar z}{2i}$in terms of $z,\bar z$ and obtain after an easy calculation $(1+2i)z+(1-2i)\bar z-2=0$  .

Answer (score 2):

The usual method is to take two complex numbers on the line $a$ and $b$, and parameterizing as $\{a+bt:t\in\Bbb R\}$.

Comment: I don't completely follow

Comment: In your example, let $a=1$ and $b=-1-i$ So the line is parameterized as $\{1+(-1-i)t: t\in\Bbb R\}$. Plug in some values for $t$ and verify that $x$ and $y$ satisfy $x-2y=1$.

Comment: So i tried your suggestion, and equated (1+(-1-i)t) = x-2y-1 and tried to solve for t hoping i could find the right complex number, alas all i got was -x+2y-i2y which i have a feeling is not right